# Recitation of rudra sukta and sri rudram at home

Tags: shiva, worship, vedic-chanting, rudra, rudram

What is rudra sukta ? Can rudra sukta or srirudram be recited daily at home while performing routine pooja of  shiva linga at home ?

Answer (score 1):

**What is a Suktam? How is it different from a Stuti/Stotram?** Sūktam means that which is the juice/essence of a concept. For example, DharmaSūktam conveys the essence of the cumulative literature associated with dharma. **So Rudra Sūktams are the cumulative essence of the concept called Rudra.** So how is this different from Stuti/Stotram? Sūktas are composed using a specific vedic metre and are used for Svāhākāras and Sāmans.

Can I recite them daily? To understand this, I have to go a little further so kindly bear with me.

Please note: people usually misinterpret Svāhākāra, Anuvākam & Sūktam.
Svāhākāras are the presentions of oblations into the fire altar using Anuvākam verse used in making oblation. Many Anuvākam collectively become Sūktam. Anuvākam can be picked from various Sūktas during Yajna. Adhyāyas are chapters of Veda-Saṃhitās, and these ādhyāya addressing Rudra are called **Rudrādhyāya** and hymns addressing Rudra are called **Rudrīya**

**Śrī Rudram vs Śatarudrīya, and which one can I read?** At the center of these 5 Principle Sākhā stands the KṛṣṇaYajur (Black Yajur). In Kṛṣṇa Yajur there are 7 kandas (cantos), making the 4th kanda it's center. This 4th kanda has 9 Prapathaka/Prayāya (chapters/Prashnas), making the 5th chapter it’s center. This 5th chapter with 11 homages is called the **Rudra Prashna or Śrī Rudram**. This makes Rudra Prashna the kernel/core of Vedam and is the home of the Panchakshari (five syllables) Mahamantra which is ‘Om Nama Śivāya‘. Many renowned scholars like Śrī Chaganti call Rudra Prashna the heart and well-guarded nucleus of Vedam. **Śatarudrīya/Çatarudriya**, on the other hand, comes from the Rudrādhyāyas Sukla Yajur Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā Saṃhitā (White Yajur) belonging to 16th Kanda (Also present in Maitrāyaṇī Saṃhitā of Kṛṣṇa Yajur). It contains 6×11 = 66 homages with 425 oblations given to One Hundred aspects of Rudra – hence the word Śata/Çata, meaning hundred. This 425 is divided into three sets – 360 formulas represent 30 phases of the moon multiplied by 12 months/masa in a year, 30 formulas correspond to the nights of each month, and 35 formulas representing the 13th month called Adhika Masa are dedicated to the SELF (the divine spark Agni and Prajāpati). Why 35? The Self on the physical level is represented with 30 limbs + 2 feet + 2 vital prāṇa + 1 head/mind totaling 35.

**Coming to your question: can I read them?** As you can see the meticulous and mathematical precision involved in these Sūktam. So my question to you is, do you think you can chat them with perfect mathematical precision? If yes, then go ahead. If not, then let's not play with these very powerful sounds created by Rishis. Many acharyas gave us magnificant stotram, stuties and dandakas.. we can read them and sing them to our heart's desire. Or we can study under a master and achieve perfect chant using Vedic Metre.

[Source link for detailed readers](http://namahshivaya.net/the-pinnacle-of-rudra-sri-rudram-rudra-prashna-satarudriya/).

Answer (score 0):

A collection of Rudra Mantras from Rigveda is generally called Rudra Suktam (रुद्रसूक्तम्) whereas Rudraprashnah (रुद्रप्रश्नः) or Sri Rudram is from the Krishna Yajurveda Taittiriya Samhita. There is also Rudradhyaya in Shukla Yajurveda Madhyandina Shakha.  Sri Rudram is chanted by many people daily (Nitya Parayana) and also chanted while doing Puja and Abhisheka of Linga at home.  Generally people who are formally intiated are the ones who chant but nowadays many people learn it from YouTube etc., and chant.